# User SS64 updating URLs, but old URLs still work

Tags: discussion, status-planned

A user named [SS64](https://superuser.com/users/391480/ss64) is editing several links to the (really good resource) site ss64.com on various posts, changing the path from https://ss64.com/osx/... to https://ss64.com/mac/...

The old ..`/osx/`... URLs still work, so I've declined several of the edits for not being a change. However, as this may be some legit representative of that site, I want to give them opportunity to let us know whether this is an intentional and valid change to support planned changes to SS64.com.

Comment: I'm guessing it's just future proofing. The `/osx` links auto-redirect to `/mac`, so at the very least the benefit is saving a redirect. But if there are lots of links it would save a lot of of time to have them updated by the bulk replacement tool that CMs have access to, rather than manually editing them. (I believe the threshold for using the tool is 50 potential replacements)

Comment: Maybe if a mod could tag this as `status-review` it would bring it to the attention of the powers that be, to consider. There are probably links on AD & SO  too, so it needs someone with a global overview.

Comment: Can this bulk replacement tool automatically update each URL to the one it redirects to, or does this have to be a simple change like `/osx/` to `/mac/`? I ask because I've done a lot of URL update edits, typically where a docs.microsoft.com (or other subdomain) URL redirected to a learn.microsoft.com URL. My reasoning is that a redirecting link today might be a broken one tomorrow, and there have been MS links in the past which have become broken after site rearrangements. But if there's an automated tool that could do all this site-wide...

Comment: I don't think it's automatic.

Comment: I'm wondering if this should be raised on main Meta to draw attention to the proposed fix method. As it's bound to relate to more than one stack, it would seem appropriate.

Comment: SS64's a pretty important resource for command line help IIRC. And yeah, the dev/cm tool for mass replacements is probably the better option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: After revisiting this question and experimenting with inputs into the bulk replacement tool, I found a total of 52 instances of the `/osx/` URL on Super User.

So good news, that means I can request the bulk replacement action from the development team (CM access to the tool is only for queries). That's been submitted and I'll update this post when the changes have been completed.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, I do run SS64.com. I moved the pages to live under `/mac` as a better representation of the OS name now that it is no longer called OS X.

There is a redirect in place, but editing the links on Stack Overflow will allow them to go direct to the canonical URL.

Comment: First, cool. Second, thanks! Your site has been a help to me for many years through my stages of tech involvement. The moderators should be able to use their bulk tool to update all of the ss64 links without you (or me) having to find and modify each individually.

Comment: I'd like to add my thanks as well - SS64 is one of the most useful, helpful sites out there!

Comment: I'm another user who has bookmarked SS64, and often link to it in answers that I post here in Super User and Stack Overflow. Thank you for a most excellent resource.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a Community Manager following up on this request. There are 34 instances of the `/osx/` URL on Super User. Typically we don't send replacement requests to developers unless there are 50 or more instances, since below that it's a manageable amount of manual editing.

I'm happy to list out the specific URLs here, or elsewhere if something else makes more sense. Let me know what is best.

It's worth noting that there are notable (more than 1) instances on the following sites:

- Stack Overflow (147)
- Ask Different (118)
- Unix & Linux (30)

I'm open to approaching those three communities on their Metas and proposing the replacements. I'd refer to this post in such a message. If we did at least one of the other sites, I can request the change from developers for the bulk update. Let me know if this is something I should proceed with.

Comment: I think it makes sense to tackle this cross-site for the whole network - get them all updated at once. You mention those 3 sites have notable amounts of the links. I assume that means there's a few sites with 1 or 2 links as well?

Comment: @Robotnik There are 11 other sites that have just 1 instance. Then the next lowest count was Unix & Linux with 30.